# How to clear memory when rendering new image in ARKit?

Tags: swift, memory, uiimage, arkit

I am working with Swift ARKit for the first time, and in my renderer didUpdate method I provide the user with the option to change the image being rendered.  When they change the image, I create a new image (using a resized image) and use that image for the contents of the faceGeometry node.  The problem is, whenever this occurs, it adds about 50-100mb to the memory use, and if they do it enough times then the app crashes.

How do I clear the memory for the old images every time I add a new image?  Am I missing a step or should I not be updating/creating an image in the didUpdate method?

```
func renderer(
    _ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer,
    didUpdate node: SCNNode,
    for anchor: ARAnchor) {

    guard let faceGeometry = node.geometry as? ARSCNFaceGeometry,
        let faceAnchor = anchor as? ARFaceAnchor
        else { return }


    if imageChanged {
        let material = faceGeometry.firstMaterial!

            let resizedImg = resizeImage(image: primaryImage!, targetSize: CGSize(width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight))

            let expandedSize = CGSize(width: 1000, height: 1000)

            let imageOnBlueCanvas = drawImageOnCanvas(resizedImg, canvasSize: expandedSize, canvasColor: .clear, x: imageX, y: imageY)

            let v = UIImageView(image: imageOnBlueCanvas)

            material.diffuse.contents = v// Example texture map image.
            material.lightingModel = .physicallyBased


        imageChanged = false
    }


    faceGeometry.update(from: faceAnchor.geometry)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by using single references for all my images, and updating those references whenever I create a new image.  This releases the old memory and I no longer get memory overflow.